# Intersection Dense and Regular Closed Sets is Dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space.  It seems intuitive to me that if $D$ is dense in $X$ and $K=cl(int(K))$ *(ie: $K$ is a regular closed set in $X$)* then
$$
cl(D\cap K) = K,
$$
that is $D$ is dense in $K$....but how to show this/is it actually true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$int(K) \subset cl(D\cap K)$ because if $x \in int(K)$ and $U$ is any open set containing $X$ then  $U\cap int(K)$ is a nonempty open set; so it intersects $D$. Thus every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $D \cap K$ proving that  $int(K) \subset cl(D\cap K)$. Now just take closure on both sides to see that $K \subset cl(D\cap K)$. The reverse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: Thank you Kavi.  Though I'm curious, does the argument still hold if we consider relative interiors and relative closures?

Comment: I don't quite understand this question. Relative to what?

Comment: Say, relative to a closed subspace $\tilde{X}$ of $X$.

Comment: Yes, the result is still true and you only have to replace the metric space $X$ by the closure of $K$ in the proof.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much Kavi :)