# Closure of the intersection of closed set with a dense set

Tags: general-topology

This question is a related to a similar one already answered in [Intersection Dense and Regular Closed Sets is Dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309301/intersection-dense-and-regular-closed-sets-is-dense?rq=1).  If $X$ is a Tychonoff space, $D$ is a dense subset of $X$ and $C$ is a closed subset of $X$, can one show that $C=\overline{C\cap X}$ (where the bar means the closure)?

Comment: What *is* true: for $U$ open, $D$ dense we have $\overline{U \cap D} =\overline{ U}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you meant to write  $C =\overline {C \cap D}$

Not true. In $\mathbb R$ let $D=\mathbb Q$ and $C=\{0\}\cup \{\frac {\sqrt 2} n: n \geq 1\}$. Then $D \cap C=\{0\}$. So the equality does  not hold.

Answer (score 1):

$C\cap X$ is just $C$ (and $C=\overline C$). If you are thinking about the identity $C=\overline{C\cap D}$, then consider $X=\Bbb R$, $C=\text{Cantor's set}$, $D=\Bbb R\setminus C$. Or $C=\{\sqrt 2\}$ and $D=\Bbb Q$.